# How to add custom scrollbar in angular 4 and initialize the scrollbar when required in the child-component.ts

Tags: angular, perfect-scrollbar

I have installed the ngx-perfect-scrollbar in my angular app , but i want to customize it like when my div height will increase it should be initialized and destroyed when I want . Can Anyone help me how to use the css and js for this perfect scrollbar.

Comment: adding a minimal example which uses ngx-perfect-scrollbar in stackblitz will make it easier to help

Comment: Hey Alqbal i can't share  that but could you share the link of example  for ngx-perfect-scrollbar with custom css and ts files so i can study them and apply to my code. thanks this could help me ...!